# How do I Substract a column value from 2 different Table using an After Trigger in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables orders and products, both have a quantity column with values in them. I am trying to subtract the quantity column on the products table from the quantity column on the orders table using an after trigger. The trigger will be on the orders table.This is what I have so far:

```
delimiter //

 Create Trigger OQminusPQ
   After Insert ON orders
   For Each Row

  Begin

  Select products.Quantity - orders.Quantity

   end

 //
 delimiter ;
```

Error: I am not allowed to return  result set from a trigger, so what should I do ( RESOLVED)!!!!

UPDATE:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER OQminusPQ
  AFTER INSERT ON orders
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE PQMOQ INT;
  SELECT products.Quantity - orders.Quantity
    INTO PQMOQ
    FROM products
    WHERE products.ProductID = orders.ProductID;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

NOTE: I've created my trigger, now how do I show my result?

Comment: That's correct.  What do you want to do with the difference? save it to another column, update the quantity in products?

Comment: save it to another column

Answer (score 1):

In a row trigger, you generally can't (and usually don't want to) directly query the table the trigger is attached to. (Look up the "Mutating Table" problem.) Instead, in an `INSERT` row trigger you have access to a pseudorecord called `NEW`, which contain the new record ***as it will be after the trigger code exits.***. (In a `DELETE` row trigger you instead have the pseudorecord `OLD` which contains the record as it was *before* the trigger fires, and in an `UPDATE` row trigger you have both `OLD` and `NEW`.)

Note that in a **BEFORE** trigger you can actually change the record before it's written by changing the values in `NEW`; in an **AFTER** trigger you don't have this option.

You would do something like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER OQminusPQ
  AFTER INSERT ON orders
  BEFORE EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE products
    SET Quantity = Quantity - NEW.Quantity;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Almost right. In an INSERT trigger you can't access OLD, since there is no OLD value. In an UPDATE trigger you have both values and in a DELETE trigger you don't have the NEW value. Changing of the NEW value inside the trigger can only by done in trigger that is set BEFORE the INSERT/UPDATE

Comment: Good catch. I'll correct that immediately. (Not enough coffee yet.)

Comment: It came up with an error  ( Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger)

Comment: Yes. If the "other column" is in the same table as the trigger, you have to do it as a **BEFORE** trigger, as I've written it.

Comment: I understand that, but I have to use an After Trigger as stated in my question.

Comment: Why do you have to use an **AFTER** trigger?

Comment: I tis  an assignment, the code is where I got so far. I'm going to update it now.

Comment: It might help if you include the problem statement in your question, so we know what other constraints we're dealing with.

Comment: 1 FK named ProductID

Comment: I meant "restrictions on the possible solution." :)

Comment: oh..." Create an after trigger on the Orders table to deduct the ordered quantity from the products quantity". So i have to have an after trigger, then test it out and show my result via screen shot .

Comment: Okay, so you're updating the `products` table? That's actually quite easy; let me just edit my answer. (*Still* haven't had enough coffee!)

Comment: kind of. I don't want to change the values in the products or orders table, instead I want to possibly create a new column where the ending result can be stored. Do you think that would be a cleaner way of doing it or just updating the product table in accordance to the trigger?

Comment: If you add a new column you will essentially be storing two *different* values for `quantity` in the *same* row, which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I see what your mean, but I could Just update that column name to say ( Inventory)? That way i can keep my values in my product and order table, while having an inventory column with values of whats left from product.quantity - orders.quantity.???

Comment: Then what does `product.quantity` represent? The important thing is that your table structures make sense from the standpoint of your data model.

Comment: Your right!, what about creating a new table just to show the result for the sake of showing the result because i still need a screen shot of it.

Comment: What database client are you using? If you can use the `mysql` command-line client, just do a `SELECT`, then an `UPDATE`, then another `SELECT` and shoot that.

Comment: Not sure how you'd do it, then. You might have to submit two screen shots.

Comment: Yeah I might have to, Thanks a lot I've learn a lot from you.

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck with school.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `SELECT` statement inside a trigger. Use a `SELECT INTO` statement.